# javascript return URL onClick

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a html form with a dropdown list of car models and a blank frame below that. I'd like to display a url related to the selected car in the frame when the submit button is pushed. I have it working and displays the current cars value in the frame, but I don't know how to insert and have JS return a URL value.

the JS goes like this: (and it may be completely wrong as I'm new to this stuff...)

```
function carFormSelect (form) {
var Car = form.selCar.value;
if (Car == 'Camry'){
document.querySelector('.carSelected').innerHTML = (Car);
}
```

HTML like this:

```
<select id="selCar" name="selCar">
                    <option value="Camry">Camry</option>
                    <option value="Corolla">Corolla</option>
</select>
```

I'm assuming I need the URL to be placed where (Car) is. I tried putting the url in quotes but didn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What URL value are you referring to?

Comment: From where url will come?

Comment: If you have a frame or iframe, than set the location of that frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using a JQuery/Ajax request.

You just need to get the value when the user clicks on the Select element and send it to another page that will have a iframe with the treated with the SRC that you want (in that case the car site)

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. Did some research on JQuery site and found this ended up working: $('.carSelected').load("warrantypages/NewCamryWarranty.html" );

Comment: Glad to help you @mrmills. If my answer helped you please accept it :)